# Oracle stored procedure with hibernate 4 without named query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, orm

My Oracle SP returns only a number. But as per [official document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch18.html#sp_query), Oracle SP must return REF CURSOR for hibernate to work. So, my procedure looks like this -

```
PROCEDURE      get_action_id (
paction_id   OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
pamount            IN       NUMBER) AS ...
```

which is basically returning a single column single row cursor. And I have following java code -

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("{ ? = call get_action_id(:pamount) }").setFloat("pamount", 12.3F);
query.uniqueResult();
```

As you can imagine, my `query.uniqueResult()` is showing `java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2` error.

I am not using named query. All my hibernate configuration is in java, not in xml.

Any brother or sister is there to guide me to right direction? I am using hibernate 4.3.10 and Oracle 10g.